# Unreachable statement return in java

Tags: java, android, list

I have a method what return a list, but when i run the code, appears Unreachable statement
this method come from a aidl file and generate a map with the return.

code bellow:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Public List<String> setMethod(Map map) {
    ContentValues cv = null;
    Iterator i = map.keySet().iterator();
    Iterator j = map.values().iterator();

    if(map.isEmpty() || map == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        try {
            while(i.hasNext()) {
                String str = (String) i.next();
                Long l = (Long) j.next();
                list.add(str);
                cv.put(Storage.STR, str);
                if(Provider.insert(Storage.Table, cv) < 0) {
                   return null;
                }
            }
            if(list.isEmpty() || list == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return mPathList;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
   return list;
}
```

Anybody can give me a light what i can make for dolve it?

Comment: You might want to rephrase your text, because I can't understand what your problem is and what your question is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are returning from `try` block as well as `catch`, so the last return statement will never  be reached.

Your code has multiple return paths. You are returning from first `if` statement if your condition is met, in `else` part you have `try` block. In `try` you are returning based on `if` as well as `else`, so if no exception occurs you are guaranteed to return from `try` block, in case of exception you have a `catch` statement and you are returning from there as well. So there is no possibility that your code will continue further. Hence the last `return` statement is unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow through your code. The last `return` statement will never be run because every other branch before that leads to an other `return` statement.

Comment: Arnold: The last `return` statement will _not_ be run.

Comment: I am **not** ***Arnold***.